# Error while writing pixel values in a raster file using node gdal

Tags: gis, raster, gdal

Using the following code to raster file:

```
const gdal = require('gdal');
const dataset = gdal.open('raster.bip');
const band = dataset.bands.get(1);

band.pixels.write(0, 0, 1, 1, new Float32Array([-1111]));
```

But getting following error:

```
/Users/alok/Smart Market/Code/OpenNetwork/node_modules/gdal/lib/gdal.js:681
                return write.apply(this, [x, y, width, height, data, options.buffer_width, options.buffer_height, options.pixel_space, options.line_space]);
                             ^

Error: Failed to write 4 bytes to file. 0 bytes written
    at RasterBandPixels.write (/Users/alok/Smart Market/Code/OpenNetwork/node_modules/gdal/lib/gdal.js:681:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alok/Smart Market/Code/OpenNetwork/coverage/WriteTest.js:99:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:422:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:143:9)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
const dataset = gdal.open('raster.bip');
```

use

```
const dataset = gdal.open('raster.bip', gdal.GA_Update);
```

to allow writing to `raster.bip`

Comment: Using `gdal.GA_Update` produced an error that `TypeError: mode must be an string`. Hence I used `gdal.open("raster.bip", "w")` instead. Which produced another error that `Driver must be specified`. Please suggest which driver be specified. [Source](http://naturalatlas.github.io/node-gdal/classes/gdal.html#method-open)

Comment: Please may you provide your full code (or at least the part before your excerpt)? - Your link is for C/C++ API, not for Python module (which wrapped it).

Comment: I am using [node-gdal](https://github.com/naturalatlas/node-gdal). Link I provided above is also for node-gdal wrapper. Nothing else in the code is relevant to our problem here.